# Javascript Inactivity timer logic

Tags: javascript

I am trying to implement a inactivity timer using javascript

user should be shown a confirm "You are inactive for 2 min, pls click yes to continue"
If the user does not respond for 1 min the user will be redirected to some page

```
<script type="text/javascript">
var firstTimer = 0;
var SecondTimer = 0;
   function closewindow() {          
       window.setInterval(ShowAlert, 1000);
              }

   function ShowAlert()
   {
   firstTimer++;
   SecondTimer++;
   if(firstTimer==2)
   {
   firstTimer=0;
   confirm('Do you want to Continue');
   }    

   }

   function FinalClose()
   {
    window.setInterval(ShowFinalAlert, 1000);
   }

   function ShowFinalAlert()
   {
   if(SecondTimer==3)
   {
   window.location.href="http://www.google.com";
   }
   }
</script>
<body onload="closewindow();FinalClose();">
```

The problem with the above code is if the user does not respond to the first alert, the second timer is not firing, that is when the overall count is 3 min he should be redirected.

what is wrong with the above code.

Comment: `confirm` blocks the JavaScript execution. Use non-blocking dialog boxes.

Comment: Btw `setInterval` is not a reliable timing mechanism. Use `Date.now()` to retrieve and compare times.

Comment: Javascript's `alert` and `confirm` functions halt script execution until the user dismisses the alert. You'll need to use a custom modal dialog instead of the aforementioned native ones.

Comment: ok, will it work if i use a jQuery modal ? could you provide some references

Comment: Have a look at some of these http://www.smashingapps.com/2013/03/14/13-very-useful-jquery-modal-plugins.html

Comment: @user804401 No need to load an entire library for this. Just put the message in a DIV, and then have a "hidden" class, and set/unset that class on the DIV to show/hide it on the page. Use absolute positioning to position the box so that it looks like a modal.

Comment: Here's [**a start**](http://jsfiddle.net/yK6QK/) (that isn't working for some reason), in case anyone want's to build off of it.

Comment: thanks for your comments, i just need some help with the logic using Date.Now, could you pls provide sample logic

Comment: Should we continue this in chat?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I'll take a swing at this one

```
var idle_timer = 120000; // check every 2 minutes    
var kick_timer = 60000;  // kick user after 1 minute

var redirect = function(){
  window.location = "http://google.com";
};

var idler = function(){ 
  // start the kick timer
  var kick_timer = setTimeout(redirect, kick_timer);

  // prompt user to click OK
  if (confirm("You get the boot in 60 seconds. Do you want the boot?")) {
    clearTimeout(kick_timer);
  }
  else {
    redirect();
  }
};

//schedule idler
setInterval(idler, idle_timer);
```

Comment: thanks, but the confirm box stops the execution, when the confirm box is shown if the user does not respond to it for 1 min, it should redirect, will this work in case if I use jQuery modal

Comment: You're right. You get the idea though. Use the jQuery modal box and you'll be fine then.